# JFileChooser problems with selection of folders

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filechooser

Recently I had to use a filechooser in one of my projects. I made a frame with 8 buttons, each opening a filechooser to set some Strings.

The buttons have names from "RA1" - "RA8".

**So this is what I have:**

FileChooser method:

```
public File openDataBrowser() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        return selectedFile;
    }

    return new File("");
}
```

Actionlistener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(RA1)) path1 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA2)) path2 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA3)) path3 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA4)) path4 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA5)) path5 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA6)) path6 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA7)) path7 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(RA8)) path8 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
    else if (e.getSource().equals(finish)) {
        System.out.println(path1);
    }
}
```

So first I want to choose the files and after that I want the data to be send to another class, for testing puposes I just wanted to print the path, but it won't really work. When clicking on one of the buttons the filechooser pops up but after clicking on "open" it just brings up another one.

This happens 8 times and after that, when I press the button "finish" I get an output like this:

```
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
C:/Users/edv.BORBET/Desktop/Roentgen Auswertung neu/RA8
```

My Folders have names from "RA1" - "RA8" too.

I selected "RA8" as the last folder.
Now to my questions:

- Why does it print out the *last* path selected?
- Why does it print out this path *8 times*?
- How can I manage to get this thing working well?

*Thanks of your help!*

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding the action listener?

Comment: @KDM I now added the lines where the ActionListeners are set ^^

Comment: Are you sure RA1-RA8 are all different objects? You are using something like `RA1 = new JButton(...)`? Either all of them are referring to the same `Button` object or you are calling this part of code for each button.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I "suspect" that you're adding the `ActionListener` 8 times to the each button or something simular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

I made one `ActionListener` calling the method `doSomething()` with its calling `JButton` as argument

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomething((JButton)e.getSource());
    }
};
```

The `ActionListener` will be added to all `JButtons`.

```
RA1.addActionListener(al);
RA2.addActionListener(al);
...
RA8.addActionListener(al);
finish.addActionListener(al);
```

`doSomething()` looks like this (shortened to 3 buttons to keep it clean):

```
protected void doSomething(JButton src) {
        if (src.equals(RA1)) path1 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        else if (src.equals(RA2)) path2 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        else if (src.equals(RA3)) path3 = openDataBrowser().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        else if (src.equals(finish)) {
             System.out.println(path1);
             System.out.println(path2);
             System.out.println(path3);
      }
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem for 3 of 'em but if I do this for 8, it just prints out 1, 2 and 8 :/

Comment: Did you add the `ActionListener` to all buttons and all buttons to `doSomething()`? I didn't because in this example 3 were enough to try it.

Comment: Well I'm just stupid and forgot to change some names, thank you, it works :D